# regex operator in Splunk is not working to match results

Tags: regex, splunk

I am writing a code to simply match a regex in my search to match index field which matches app1_*, app2_*, etc

However my search below works

```
| eventcount summarize=false index=app1_*| dedup index
```

But when I use it like below it doesn't, it would be required to be done using regex since I would like to use an "OR" in the regex:

```
| eventcount summarize=false |regex index="app1_*"| dedup index
```

Answer (score 1):

The `regex` command requires uses regular expressions to match the specified field value.  It's not the same as the pattern used for matching in the `eventcount` command.  What you have in your example is a valid regular expression, but calls for the letters "app1" followed by zero or more instances of underscores.  You probably want "app1_.*", which the regex equivalent to the pattern "app1_*" in the first code sample.